# Opacity for images in body when open a sidenav

Tags: javascript

I want to change the opacity of my body when my sidenav opens. 
It works perfectly! But now I am faceing the problem, that my images won't get this effect, they stay as bright as before.
How can I change it, that the images and all the other stuff, like iframe content, gets the same effect?

This is the working code for the body opacity:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";  
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";  
    document.body.style.opacity = "0.6";
}
```

---

**Edit:** 
This could actually be somewhat of a problem if your structure is as follows:

```
<body>
   <!-- some content -->
   <div id="mySidenav">
         <!-- sidebar content -->
   </div>
</body>
```

If so, then the above function will make everything inside your body (including the sidebar) semi-transparent.

So I would try wrapping all of your content in a separate div that serves as a wrap and making that opaque:

```
<body>
   <div id="wrap">
        <!-- original body content -->
   </div>
   <div id="mySidenav">
         <!-- sidebar content -->
   </div>
</body>
```

And update the JS function to reflect this change of course:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";  
    document.getElementById("wrap").style.opacity = "0.6";
}
```

Also - if you have some css that relies on the `body` it might get a bit broken so you might have to play around with that as well.

Comment: I realized as I typed it that you are going to have this problem. I already updated my answer.

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot! Do you know way to darken the opacity instead of brighten it up btw?

Comment: Well opacity is just how much something is transparent (how much you can see through it) - so for example if your body has a white background, then the less opacity your ``#wrap`` has, the more the white will be visible. You could for example make your ``#wrap`` have the background you want and make the body below it darker and so when your wrapper gets more transparent, then the dark color on the body background will be more visible.